# Autostart recording in MediaStore

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, mediastore

I managed to record audio by sending intent with action MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION. 
But is there a way to tell MediaStore application to automatically start recording without the need for user to press record button?
I don't see relevant parameters nor [MediaStore.Audio.Media](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html) nor in MediaStore.

And same question for video...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the MediaRecorder object to record. This way you can control when and how to start the voice recording.

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

Comment: Yeah, I do it manually now. Although it would be nice to have more control over media store...